# How do I fix a "No Overload Matches This Call" error in TypeScript? SelectList onSelect property

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-props

I am currently working on a React Native app in a team. I have been trying to implement a SelectList on a page in the app that calls a handleSelection function that takes the selected value and passes it to the function on selection. My team has recently decided to move over to TypeScript files instead of Javascript files. The SelectList was working in the Javascript version but now that we switched to Typescript the onSelect prop of the SelectList is throwing a "No Overload Matches This Call" error and I'm unsure of what to do about it. The handleSelection function is supposed to filter a global list and then the list is to be displayed further down on the page.

The full error is as follows:

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SelectListProps | Readonly): SelectList', gave the following error.
Type '(selected: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SelectListProps, context: any): SelectList', gave the following error.
Type '(selected: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(79, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onSelect' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'
index.d.ts(79, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onSelect' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'

My code for the SelectList is down below:

```
import { SelectList } from 'react-native-dropdown-select-list';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("");

export default function ClientAp(){

const filterOption = [
        {key: 'All', value: 'All'},
        {key: 'Today', value: 'Today'},
        {key: 'This Week', value: 'This Week'},
        {key: 'This Month', value: 'This Month'}
    ]

const handleSelection  = (key) => {
        if(key == 'All Upcoming')
        {
            //filter by upcoming appointments
        }
        else if(key == 'Today')
        {
            //filter by appointments today
        }
        else if(key == 'This Week')
        {
            //filter by appointments this week
        }
        else if(key == "This Month")
        {
           //filter by appointments this month
        }

}

return(
    <>
       {/* more stuff up here*/}

       <View style = {styles.dropdowncont}>
                <SelectList
                    setSelected = {setSelected}
                    data = {filterOption}
                    maxHeight = {300}
                    boxStyles = {{backgroundColor:'white'}}
                    dropdownStyles = {{backgroundColor:'white'}}
                    search = {false}
                    defaultOption = {{key: 'All', value: 'All'}}
                    onSelect = {(selected) => handleSelection(selected)} {/* error on this line */}
                />
        </View>

        {/* more stuff down here */}

    </>
);
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        dropdowncont: {
        padding: 16
}
```

I have tried adding a return the to handleSelection function that returns nothing. I have also tried adding a variable type to the selected variable like so: (selected: string). I have just been trying to change the types of everything. Despite all this, there has been no progress on fixing this one error.

If any more code is needed to solve this issue, I would be happy to oblige. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`onSelect` doesn't have any parameters like the error says.

```
Type '(selected: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void
```

Use `handleSelection` in `setSelected` instead, something like this:

```
const handleSelection  = (key) => {
    setSelected(key)
    if(key == 'All Upcoming')
...

}

...

<SelectList
    setSelected = {handleSelection}
    data = {filterOption}    
    maxHeight = {300}
    boxStyles = {{backgroundColor:'white'}}
    dropdownStyles = {{backgroundColor:'white'}}
    search = {false}
    defaultOption = {{key: 'All', value: 'All'}}
/>
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! I just tried that and it's still not doing what I want it to do. The handleSelection function right now just prints things to the log for testing and it doesn't seem to be even going into the function because it's not printing anything. It needs to have the variable passed as a parameter to be able to go into the different if/else's in the function. When I try it like this, however `setSelected = {handleSelection(selected)}` it returns an identical error to the original one.